# Ansible loop over variable integer and incremente value for jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a ansible playbook, I wanto to loop over a interger and incremente a value for each file create, like that :

```
file_a :

name = a
number = 20

file_b

name = b
number = 21
```

playbook.yml

```
- name: Copy file from jinja template
  template:
    src: "jinja.j2"
    dest: "/file_{{ item }}"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
  with_items: "{{ jinja_var }}"
```

inventory.yml

```
jinja_var:
  - a
  - b
```

jinja.j2

```
name = {{ item }}
number  =
```

I have a solution with a dict who works with key, value, but I don't want to modify the inventory.yml, so hwo I can give a incremente integer through a jinja file

Answer (score 2):

Use [*loop_control*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var). For example the template

```yaml
shell> cat templates/jinja.j2 
name = {{ item }}
number = {{ index + offset }}
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    jinja_var: [a, b]
    offset: 20
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: jinja.j2
        dest: "files/file_{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ jinja_var }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index
```

give

```yaml
shell> cat files/file_a 
name = a
number = 20

shell> cat files/file_b
name = b
number = 21
```